# Removing elements based on a partial string match between 2 data frames:

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching

Suppose I have two data frames with strings in their elements:

```
B <- data.frame(c("abcd1","cdbax2","acdb3"))
colnames(B) <- "Strings"

A <- data.frame(c("abcd_11","cdba_12"))
colnames(A) <- "Strings"
```

yielding the pair of dataframes,

```
> A
  Strings
1    abcd_11
2    cdba_12
```

and

```
> B
  Strings
1   abcd1
2   cdbax2
3   acdb3
```

Desired output: B*, B purged of the partial strings that are not in A:

```
> B*
      Strings
    1   abcd1
    2   cdbax2
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Cheers

*Edit: a solution based on string length does not work, since it is possible to have differing lengths in the dataframe*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 B[max.col(-adist(A$Strings,B$Strings)),]
[1] abcd1  cdbax2
```